# POSTing with Jersey & JQuery

Tags: java, jquery, jersey

I'm having an issue POSTing to Jersey using the following...

```
var details = {username: uname, password: pword};
$.post('login',function(details){
    console.log("sent: "+details);
});
```

The correct function in my login page is being ran but both `username` and `password` are null.

The following is how I consume them...

```
   public void login(@FormParam("username") String uname,
           @FormParam("password") String pword){
       System.out.println("username = " +  uname + "password = " + pword);
   }
```

I realise what I POST isn't a form but `@FormParam` is the only `@` I can see that would fit here.

**EDIT**

Okay, I've got the following right now...

**the POST being made**

```
    var details = {'username': username, 'password': password};
$.POST('login', details,function(result){
    console.log(result);
},"json");
```

**The receiving method**

```
@POST
 public Viewable HeyStaksLogin(LoginInfo loginI){
       String uname = loginI.username;
       String pword = loginI.password;
       System.out.println("username = ");
 }
```

**The `loginInfo` class**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class LoginInfo {
public String username;
public String password;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The data is sent as the second argument of the [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function (the first being the url and the third being the success callback), like this:

```
var details = { username: username, password: password };
$.post('login', details, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Same issue. Server returning 500 error. Both params are null.

Comment: @user596186, it looks like the server expects parameters to be called `username` and `password` instead of `uname` and `pword`. Can you try modifying your request like this: `var details = { username: username, password: password };`?

Comment: I get the following response now. TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'POST'

Answer (score 0):

@FormParam is not usable in this case, as what you are posting is JSON. Here is an example of what you could do:

1) add jersey-json.jar to your project dependencies

2) define the following bean to represent the body of the message:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class LoginInfo {
    public String username;
    public String password;
}
```

3) modify the login method as follows:

```
public void login(LoginInfo li) {
    System.out.println("username = " + li.username + "; password = " + li.password);
}
```

Comment: Still isn't fixing my problem. It's claiming `method undefined`

Comment: OK, I thought you are skipping the annotations from your code snippet just to keep it short. Of course, your login method needs to be annotated with @POST annotation and it should also be annotated with @Consumes("application/json"). Instead of returning void, you could return Response and the return statement could look like this: `return Response.seeOther(url_you_want_to_redirect_to).build();`.

Answer (score 0):

try @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) annotation for your serverside method